# clipboard and drag and drop fileuploader (HTML + JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, blueimp

I'm searching for a implementation of a fileuploader with HTML and JS technic. The target is having it running on most platforms but at least on Google Chrome, FireFox and IE9+ with the ability of copy and paste screenshots and drag and drop.

Unfortunately there aren't many ones out there. I prefer the [blueimp](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) one because it has an easy implementation. Another one could be one like [imgur](http://imgur.com) uses. But therefore I haven't found any git-repo.

The primary target is to use it in GC, FF and IE9+ with the features of making screenshots and paste them and furthermore have the ability of drag and drop. Even with fallbacks like silverlight or flash.

Any advice?

Comment: a html5/js drag and drop file uploader: http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload

Comment: Thanks, but that is not my main target, as it doesn't support copy and paste...

Comment: blueimp file uploader which you already know is a nice choice which worked for me perfectly in my last project. But as you said, it currently lacks copy and paste to upload feature. Hope the owner will see this comment and try to implement that feature in near future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I got my own solution.

I implemented it into the [blueimp fileuploader](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/).

@Ray Nicholus, just in case u need any help try this for pasting images in FF:

Insert a content editable div:

```
<div id="editable" style="position: absolute; left: -99999;" contenteditable></div>
```

In case of paste use this:

```
document.onpaste = function(event){
                    $('#editable').focus();

                    setTimeout(function()
                    {
                       //get the base64 image
                       var src = $('#editable').find('img:first').attr('src');
                       //doing something with the image... and clearing the div
                       $('#editable').empty();
                    }, 10);
```

**EDIT**: Of course you have to validate whether it is an image or not.

Thanks a lot for your effort. I will give a try if your fine uploader is online with the new feature ;) also I hope there will be a bit more specific demo where I can give it a try without downloading the sample.

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

I've used this one in the past

https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

and if I remember correctly, it worked very well.

Now it moved to  https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader

It doesn't use flash, and it has the ability to drag&drop.

What do u mean with "the features of making screenshots and paste them" ?

Comment: I mean that I want to take a screenshot for example of my webpage containing an error and paste it directly into the fileuploader. I know that it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

[Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com) supports copy and pasting images to upload in 3.4, which is releasing in the next couple days.  This support initially only exists for Chrome.  Getting this to work in Firefox and perhaps other browsers that don't properly support the Clipboard API will happen in another version as this will require a bit more work as well as, potentially, some server-side magic.

You can read more about copy/paste image support in Fine Uploader in [a blog post I wrote on the topic](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/03/upload-image-via-paste-in-34.html).  If you are interested, you can also examine and comment on [the associated feature case in Github](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/487).

Full Disclosure: I'm the primary maintainer of Fine Uploader.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! Unfortunately it's not open source. For FireFox a simple trick did it for me. Just put a div contenteditable and after the paste event you will get the base64 image.

Comment: @daniel.didusch It is open source.  Have a look at [the Github repo](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader).

Comment: @daniel.didusch Also note that your approach will not work for images hosted on servers that do not permit CORS.

Comment: Thanks I saw it after I posted my answer to you. There's no problem with CORS ;)

Also I'm trying running the [blueimp fileuploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). Which works great so far. Only the copy and paste doesn't work in FF. My approach was a hidden field which works great. But now I don't know how to build the file-object.